# Where's my money

Tags: banking, pennsylvania

I deposited $4,169 into my checking account the bank put a 7 day hold till it cleared. The next day I check my account it shows Debit -p in process -$4,169

Comment: Could the check have been bad? That's what would happen if the payer doesn't have the money or the check was fake. Only your bank can tell you why they took it back out.

Comment: This question needs a lot more information to be a reasonable quality but I have to agree with @Aganju about the provenance of the cheque.

Comment: This is a question you should really ask your bank.

Comment: It *could* be a case of bad user interface. ["Debit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits) means you pay money. A debit with a minus-sign in front *could* mean that you are going to *receive* money. But really, when you don't understand what the online banking app is trying to tell you, call your bank and ask them to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you may have been the victim of a scam.

One common way this works is that you are given a check for some amount (say $5000) but asked to send or give a small amount (say $1000) to someone else.  The $5000 check is never real but it takes the bank some time to detect this.  Once they do, they reverse the charge and you owe the bank any part of the $5000 you may have spent.  While the money still appears in your account, you have given $1000 to someone else (the scammer or an accomplice), which you cannot get back.

Comment: This answer seems to be very speculative. The OP didn't write anything about sending money somewhere else.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, it is speculative, however, the check deposit was clearly reversed.  Given that this comes as a surprise, it's most likely either a scam or just a normal bounced check.  I have to imagine that anyone who regularly deposits checks for $4000 would know how bounced checks work so I think scam is the most likely scenario.

Comment: I agree with Philipp. The cheque bounced is certain. That's it's a scam is speculative. I've written cheques that bounced by accident.

Comment: I've had checks where the writer's John Hancock crossed the MICR line and caused a misread.  Bounce-ola!  Now when my deposit-by-photo app asks me to double-check the account and routing numbers, *I do it*...